# How to map flat object to deep DTO with abstract fields?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I have the following model class:

```
@Data
public class M {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private int height;
}
```

and the following Dto class:

```
@Data
public class Dto {
  private String name;
  private B nested;
}

@Data
public class C extends B {
  private int height;
}
```

where B is an abstract class:

```
@Data
public abstract class B {
  private int age;
}
```

I'd like to use ModelMapper to translate a Model instance to a Dto instance with the model's age and height properties translated to a C object properly populated.

An example:

```
model = { name: "Steve", age: 35, height: 185 } of Model
```

to:

```
dto = { name: "Steve", nested: { age: 35, height: 185 } of C } of Dto
```

I tried the following:

```
mapper.createTypeMap(Model.class, Dto.class).addMappings(new PropertyMap<Model, Dto>() {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    map(source, destination.getNested());
  }
});

mapper.createTypeMap(Model.class, C.class);
```

ending up with `dto.getNested() == null`.

Also tried to add

```
public Model getSelf() { return this; }
```

to the Model class (out of base curiosity) and redefine the property mapper to have:

```
with(new Provider<C>(req => new C())).map(source.getSelf(), destination.getNested());
```

which populated `dto.getNested()`, but didn't populate `dto.getNested().getHeight()`.

Is this achievable with ModelMapper?

Thanks for all advice.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, there is no way to configure the mapper other than having a provider and list up all the flat-to-nested properties manually. Since I wanted to avoid that, I got stuck with the converter below:

```
    Converter<M, C> converter = new Converter<M, C>() {
        @Override
        public C convert(MappingContext<M, C> context) {
            C c = new C();
            mapper.map(context.getSource(), c);
            return c;
        }
    };
```

, and use this converter in the M to Dto configuration to map `source` to `destination.getNested()`. This also assumes that the converter needs to have access to the mapper. Meh.